# Cloud Video Intelligence API error 400 & 504

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, video-intelligence-api

When I tried to call Cloud Video Intelligence API to detec subtitle in **local video file**.It always returned error 400 or 504, but use gas is fine.I have tried to adjusted timeout in Cloud Video Intelligence config but it still show error 400 with invalid argument.

this is my python code for detecting video subtitle:

```
"""This application demonstrates detection subtitles in video using the Google Cloud API.

Usage Examples:

    use video in google cloud storge:
        python analyze.py text_gcs gs://"video path"
    use video in computer:
        python analyze.py text_file video.mp4

"""

import argparse
import io
from google.cloud import videointelligence
from google.cloud.videointelligence import enums


def video_detect_text_gcs(input_uri):
    # [START video_detect_text_gcs]
    """Detect text in a video stored on GCS."""
    from google.cloud import videointelligence

    video_client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()
    features = [videointelligence.enums.Feature.TEXT_DETECTION]
    config = videointelligence.types.TextDetectionConfig(language_hints=["zh-TW","en-US"])
    video_context = videointelligence.types.VideoContext(text_detection_config=config)

    operation = video_client.annotate_video(input_uri=input_uri, features=features, video_context=video_context)

    print("\nSubtitle detecting......")
    result = operation.result(timeout=300)

    # The first result is retrieved because a single video was processed.
    annotation_result = result.annotation_results[0]
    subtitle_data=[ ]
    for text_annotation in annotation_result.text_annotations:
        text_segment = text_annotation.segments[0]
        start_time = text_segment.segment.start_time_offset
        frame = text_segment.frames[0]
        vertex=frame.rotated_bounding_box.vertices[0]
        if text_segment.confidence > 0.95 and vertex.y >0.7:
         lists=[text_annotation.text,start_time.seconds+ start_time.nanos * 1e-9,vertex.y]
         subtitle_data=subtitle_data+[lists]
    length=len(subtitle_data)
    subtitle_sort=sorted(subtitle_data,key = lambda x: (x[1],x[2]))
    i=0
    subtitle=[ ]
    while i<length :
        subtitle=subtitle+[subtitle_sort[i][0]]
        i=i+1

    with open("subtitle.txt",mode="w",encoding="utf-8") as file:
       for x in subtitle:
            file.write(x+'\n')




def video_detect_text(path):
    # [START video_detect_text]
    """Detect text in a local video."""
    from google.cloud import videointelligence

    video_client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()
    features = [videointelligence.enums.Feature.TEXT_DETECTION]
    video_context = videointelligence.types.VideoContext()

    with io.open(path, "rb") as file:
        input_content = file.read()

    operation = video_client.annotate_video(
        input_content=input_content,  # the bytes of the video file
        features=features,
        video_context=video_context
    )
    print("\nSubtitle detecting......")
    result = operation.result(timeout=300)

    # The first result is retrieved because a single video was processed.
    annotation_result = result.annotation_results[0]
    subtitle_data=[ ]
    for text_annotation in annotation_result.text_annotations:
        text_segment = text_annotation.segments[0]
        start_time = text_segment.segment.start_time_offset
        frame = text_segment.frames[0]
        vertex=frame.rotated_bounding_box.vertices[0]
        if text_segment.confidence > 0.95 and vertex.y >0.7:
         lists=[text_annotation.text,start_time.seconds+ start_time.nanos * 1e-9,vertex.y]
         subtitle_data=subtitle_data+[lists]
    length=len(subtitle_data)
    subtitle_sort=sorted(subtitle_data,key = lambda x: (x[1],x[2]))
    i=0
    subtitle=[ ]
    while i<length :
        subtitle=subtitle+[subtitle_sort[i][0]]
        i=i+1

    with open("subtitle.txt",mode="w",encoding="utf-8") as file:
       for x in subtitle:
            file.write(x+'\n')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
    )
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command")

    detect_text_parser = subparsers.add_parser(
        "text_gcs", help=video_detect_text_gcs.__doc__
    )
    detect_text_parser.add_argument("path")

    detect_text_file_parser = subparsers.add_parser(
        "text_file", help=video_detect_text.__doc__
    )
    detect_text_file_parser.add_argument("path")



    args = parser.parse_args()


    if args.command == "text_gcs":
        video_detect_text_gcs(args.path)
    if args.command == "text_file":
        video_detect_text(args.path)
```

This is error report:

```
    Ghuang@/Users/Ghuang/Documents/GitHub/Video-subtitles-detection$ python3 analyze.py text_file video.mp4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ghuang/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Ghuang/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/Users/Ghuang/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 729, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
    details = "Deadline Exceeded"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1587691109.677447000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.24.10:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Deadline Exceeded","grpc_status":4}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analyze.py", line 144, in <module>
    video_detect_text(args.path)
  File "analyze.py", line 90, in video_detect_text
    video_context=video_context
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/videointelligence_v1/gapic/video_intelligence_service_client.py", line 303, in annotate_video
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "/Users/Ghuang/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Ghuang/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/Users/Ghuang/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/Users/Ghuang/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Ghuang/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded
```

Comment: 400 means the request you sent the server was not accepted. 504 means the server timed out before it could return a response.  Does that help?